undefined symbol: GetMemoryChunkContext
In Ubuntu environment, when I create my PlJava extension, I get the following error: "could not load library '/usr/lib/postgresql/14/lib/libpljava-so-1.6.7.so': /usr/lib/postgresql/14/lib/libpljava-so-1.6.7.so: undefined symbol: GetMemoryChunkContext". How can I resolve this issue?
I tried export PG_CONFIG and rebuilt the project

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

A related issue has been filed on PL/Java's tracker (#487), but followup questions there still need answers from the person reporting.
